# Proving that a set is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ and $B$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Prove that the set $\{ a \times b\colon a \in A, b \in B\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am planing to show that it contains all its limit points.
But how do I show that?

Comment: Your set is a product of two closed sets. Hence, it is closed itself. But it should be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and not of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Check the Question Again...Someone had editied and changed the whole question

Comment: Yeesh, on the editing!!!  So, Rakesh Bhatt, you, the OP and no-one else, tell us once and for all.  If $a = a \in \mathbb R$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, .... b_n)\in \mathbb R^n$.  Is the term that has been written variously as $a.b$, $(a,b)$ and $a\times b$ supposed to be $(ab_1, ab_2, ...., ab_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ or $(a,b_1, b_2,.....b_n)\in \mathbb R^{n+1}$.  The first makes the must sense but it has been edited so many times it is garbled.  perhaps the notation $ab$ would be clearest.

Comment: @fleablood check it properly....It is supposed to be $\left(ab_1,ab_2....ab_n\right)$. The new set so formed is supposed to be in $\mathbb{R}_n$. the Question ask to show that it is closed in $\mathbb{R}_n$ not  $\mathbb{R}_{n+1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For brevity write $AB = \{ab : a \in A, b \in B\}$.

Suppose that $x$ is a limit point of $AB$. We want to show that $x \in AB$. Since $x$ is a limit point, there exists a sequence $(a_n b_n)$ where $a_n \in A$ and $b_n \in B$, such that $a_n b_n \to x$.

As $A$ is compact, $a_n$ has a subsequence, say $(a_{n_k})$, that converges to some point $a \in A$. (Note that this means that $a \neq 0$.)

Observe that $(a_{n_k} b_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n b_n)$, hence also converges to $x$.

Since $a_{n_k}$ is always nonzero, we can form the quotient 
$$b_{n_k} = \frac{a_{n_k}b_{n_k}}{a_{n_k}} \to \frac{x}{a}$$
In other words, $b_{n_k}$ converges to the limit $b = x/a$, which is in $B$ because $B$ is closed.

Thus we have established that $x = a(x/a) = ab \in AB$ as desired.

Comment: What do you mean by two quotients that are in the formula on a separate line? Numerator $a_{n_k}b_{n_k}$ should be treated as a single symbol, not as a usual numerical product.

Answer (score 0):

you have to notice that every compact set in an hausdorff space is closed. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a hausdorff space, it follows, that $A$ is compact and so the product $A \times B \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is also compact

Comment: Check the Question Again...Someone had editied and changed the whole question

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is compact in an Hausdorff space then  $A$ is closed. Now $A$ and $B$ are closed sets. Then $A\times B\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is closed.

Comment: Check the Question Again...Someone had editied and changed the whole question